# How can I Download images from PG DataBase table on server to Production Machine?

Tags: image, postgresql, paperclip, activeadmin, psql

I need advise about how I can grab images from `products table` in an `postgres` database that is running on a server. We changed the Application lately and now the images for all products should be stored in another table called `images`.

So we basically need to grab the images from the server and upload them again through `ActiveAdmin`to the new `images` table.

I have never done anything like this before, and I don´t want to mess up or delete the database. Thats why I'm asking about this here instead of following some old outdated tutorial after google search :)

So my question is :

1. How can I download only the images from the `products table` to my local production machine.?
2. I don't want to delete the database or anything, Just want those images to be downloaded to my production machine. It is ok if the images are still in the old table. Just want to Copy/Paste them, and then upload them manually again.
3. I can access the `psql`shell on the server. And my plan is to do it through the shell. I don´t have PGAdmin connected to the server.

this is how the images are in the `products` table

```
                           image_file_name                        | image_content_type | image_file_size 
---------------------------------------------------------------+--------------------+-----------------
 Green-Pins.png                                                | image/png          |          713679
 500156.jpg                                                    | image/jpeg         |          353280
```

Hope anyone can help me with this.

Here is sample from the new `image`table. I just uploaded three new images to it.

```
    mystore=> SELECT * FROM images;
 id | product_id |            image_file_name             | image_file_size | image_content_type |         created_at         |         updated_at         
----+------------+----------------------------------------+-----------------+--------------------+----------------------------+----------------------------
  1 |        104 | Screen_Shot_2016-05-26_at_15.09.50.png |          513442 | image/png          | 2017-09-28 16:19:35.944218 | 2017-09-28 16:19:35.944218
  2 |        104 | Screen_Shot_2016-05-26_at_15.08.32.png |          760101 | image/png          | 2017-09-28 16:19:35.954766 | 2017-09-28 16:19:35.954766
  3 |        104 | Screen_Shot_2016-05-27_at_00.44.39.png |          323387 | image/png          | 2017-09-28 16:19:35.962563 | 2017-09-28 16:19:35.962563
(3 rows)
```

Comment: How are the images stored in the database?

Comment: hi @TZHX  its a string in the `products` table `create_table "products", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "title"
    t.string   "image"`

Comment: What is the string? A base64 representation of the image? A filepath?

Comment: @TZHX It's not a filepath, The images was uploaded by using Paperclip through Active admin, please see the update I added to the question.

Comment: Looks like the images them selves are not in the database. If they were in the database you would either expect a column with OID's pointing to large objects, a bytea column containing binary unreadable data, or a string column with base64 encoded data.

Comment: @Eelke  I added a sample from the new Image table, Those three images are visible on the web.  Can't see any `OID's pointing to large objects, a bytea column containing binary unreadable data, or a string column with base64 encoded data.`

Comment: Still quite sure the images are not in postgres but somewhere else. You probably have to dig down into paperclip to find out where or simply do a file search on your server(s). If you have seperate db and web server they probably are on the web server not on the db server.

Comment: You are right @Eelke the images are stored in the `~/mystore/current/public/system/products/images` now I just have to find a way to DL that folder to my local Machine

Comment: If you have ssh access to that server you can use scp commandline tool or winscp on windows to copy files over ssh.

Comment: @Eelke I used SCP and it worked like a charm, thank you... you can put that in as an answer if you want